# Problems with synchronization inside event dispatch thread

Tags: java, swing, synchronization, thread-safety

I was working with java.net.Authenticator to create a blocking dialog that requests proxy login/password from the user first time any connection is established through proxy. Authenticator works just fine, but i got into some strange problem when i tried to synchronize the method that displays the input dialog.

Here is an abstract working code example of the problem i found:

```
private static JFrame frame;

public static void main ( String[] args )
{
    frame = new JFrame ( "Frame" );
    frame.add ( new JLabel ( "This is main application" ) );
    frame.setSize ( 500, 500 );
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo ( null );
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation ( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
    frame.setVisible ( true );

    // Cycling thread
    new Thread ( new Runnable ()
    {
        public void run ()
        {
            while ( true )
            {
                // Opening new dialog in a separate event dispatch thread
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater ( new Runnable ()
                {
                    public void run ()
                    {
                        showSomeLockingDialog ();
                    }
                } );

                // Wait 3 seconds before next window
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep ( 3000 );
                }
                catch ( InterruptedException e )
                {
                    e.printStackTrace ();
                }
            }
        }
    } ).start ();
}

private static final Object lock = new Object ();

private static void showSomeLockingDialog ()
{
    synchronized ( lock )
    {
        // Output to see that this method is not finished yet
        System.out.println ( "Method start" );

        // Modal thread-blocking dialog
        JDialog dialog = new JDialog ( frame, "Lock" );
        dialog.add ( new JLabel ( "This should be blocking other dialogs" ) );
        dialog.pack ();
        dialog.setLocationRelativeTo ( null );
        dialog.setModal ( true );
        dialog.setVisible ( true );

        // Output to see that this method is not finished yet
        System.out.println ( "Method end" );
    }
}
```

So basically:

1. There is a visible main frame (actually, just to keep JVM running)
2. There is cycling Thread that requests showSomeLockingDialog() method in each cycle
3. Method is synchronized on the "lock" object
4. There is console output at the method start and end

So if you run this example you will see that each cycle a new dialog pops ignoring synchronization even if you do not close previous dialog. I have also tried simple method synchronization instead but it has the same effect.

Everything changes if we change the way we call showSomeLockingDialog() a bit:

```
    new Thread ( new Runnable ()
    {
        public void run ()
        {
            showSomeLockingDialog ();
        }
    } ).start ();
```

(just using a separate thread instead of calling method inside event dispatch thread)

This way everything works the way i expect it to work - new dialog calls are blocked until the one that was called before is closed.

And that is pretty strange - what is so special about event dispatch thread that synchronization is getting ignored?

Or if it is actually a bug - is there any workaround?
Maybe i am missing something huge...

**Some thoughts:** It seems to me that modal dialog setVisible method acts differently inside event dispatch thread (otherwise it would block the whole interface if called from there). But how does that affect synchronization...

**P.S.** And no, i can't just use 2nd (working) example in my specific case, because i am not calling that method where i want - it is getting called from random place, mostly from standart JDK classes (when any resource that is getting loaded from internet - either image in JLabel, some URL input stream or anything else).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Dialog's [setVisible javadoc documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Dialog.html#setVisible%28boolean%29):

```
It is OK to call this method from the event dispatching thread because 
the toolkit ensures that other events are not blocked while this method
is blocked.
```

And based on that java synchronized blocks are reentrant, the following is what is happening for each invokeLater:

1. The dispatch thread is calling `showSomeLockingDialog`
2. taking the lock or reentering
3. Open window -> blocked until closing the dialog

Since blocking is just for the setVisible and not for other events (ie. other invokeLaters) then you get the specified behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the doc link, seems my guess about setVisible method was right. Since i can neither leave this method (before retrieving information from the dialog) nor lock it with something else (its EDT, so if i lock it - interface will lock aswell for as long as the lock is active) - i can only create my own synchronization "logic" for this specific case, right?

Comment: You are correct about the dispatch thread. You should refrain from doing long operations with it or blocking it. It seems that you need to do the synchronization logic yourself.

Comment: The problem is that i should return authorization token from the method which is called from EDT. I cannot block it (meaning i cannot wait another call of this method which was done earlier to return) since its EDT and blocking it will freeze the whole interface. I can't even imagine what to do in this situation... So far i just return null for all other calls that are done while authorization dialog is shown instead of showing multiply auth dialogs (so all other connections will probably fail due to recieved null token).